# Omniauth_google_oauth2 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am using Devise and Omniauth Google for Login Authentication in my application. Everything works fine, the Google login works fine in my localhost but when I try to test on a VPS, Google throws redirect_uri_mismatch. I couldn't figure out the actual problem. Please help.

My Gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
```

VPS Configuration

```
Ruby v - ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [x86_64-linux]
Rails v - Rails 4.2.5
```

Callback Controller

```
def google_oauth2
      # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

      if @user.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      else
        session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
    def failure
        redirect_to root_path
    end
```

Routes

```
devise_for :users, :path => "member",:path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :sign_up => "register"}, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations, :confirmations => 'confirmations', :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [add new redirect URI](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#setredirecturi) to your credentials

Visit [your OAuth client credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/355308797580-kv7a6sf2hqtr9692kdl3qjvc9vcgvjpi.apps.googleusercontent.com) and add URI

Comment: I have added the live url in the Google oauth credential

Comment: Could you post part of code where you provide redirect URI?

Comment: I updated my question. Please have a look. And I didn't understand where do I need to provide the redirect URI

Comment: Do you tell Devise in which controller we will implement Omniauth callbacks? It should be in config/routes.rb

Comment: Yes off course. Please see the code above, i updated the routes config.

Comment: Look at config/initialisers/omniauth.rb. May be wrong full_host there?

Comment: I don't have omniauth.rb in my application initialisers.

Comment: Try to add `require "omniauth-google-oauth2"` to config/initialisers/devise.rb

Comment: Its already in devise.rb. The problem is that, this google connect works find in localhost but not in vps. I tried to run in development mode too, google is throwing exception.

Comment: Could you post your production env?

Comment: Where shall I add it, in devise.rb or elsewhere!

Comment: To config/environments/production.rb

Comment: Are you running your app in production mode? What url you see in error about redirect_uri_mismatch?

Comment: Please check it here. www.bhansa.com this is the app

Comment: Its working for facebook only. Its not working for Google

Comment: Could you post list of acceptable redirect URIs for your application in google?

Comment: Its here https://www.dropbox.com/s/qquvtstk46ozpsr/Screen%20Shot%202016-06-27%20at%2019.25.32.png?dl=0

Comment: Check OAuth client for which you add redirect_uri. In error specified https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/355308797580-kv7a6sf2hqtr9692kdl3qjvc9vcgvjpi.apps.googleusercontent. On screen the other is specified.

Comment: I didn't understand. Could you please describe.

Comment: I think that you have another  OAuth client. Try to visit [this](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/355308797580-kv7a6sf2hqtr9692kdl3qjvc9vcgvjpi.apps.googleusercontent.com)

Comment: Shall I try creating new project

Comment: First try to visit [this](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/355308797580-kv7a6sf2hqtr9692kdl3qjvc9vcgvjpi.apps.googleusercontent.com)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail Malov, it worked. Thanks a lot. Please update your answer so that I can vote you.